# Change transform-origin on already transformed element

Tags: javascript, css

A couple of other questions have been asked that are similar to this, but none of them had sufficient answers.

I have a transformed element with a current transform origin.  I want to change the transform origin of the element and then transform it again.  The problem is that when I change the transform origin, the original transform is calculated based on the new transform origin and then the new transform takes place.

I would like to know if there is a way to make the currently transformed element stay in its exact place while I change the transform origin and then transform the element based on the new origin.

Check out this fiddle if my description is confusing.
http://jsfiddle.net/justinbchristensen/a6reyd3t/1/

```
var rotateDiv = $('#rotate-div');
var rotation = 0;

$('#rotate-btn').on('click', function() {
    rotation += 90;
    rotateDiv.css('transform', 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)');
});

$('#origin-btn').on('click', function() {
    rotateDiv.css('transform-origin', 'top right');
});
```

```
<button id="rotate-btn">1) Press To Rotate</button>
<button id="origin-btn">2) Press To Change Transform Origin</button>
<div id="container">
    <div id="rotate-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue, and am thinking of using matrix transforms to preserve the transform

Comment: @njorlsaga No. Unfortunately, I had to come up with a different solution that was radically different than this approach.

Comment: Would you share that solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to avoid `transform-origin` jumps but it is complex and time-consuming.

The jump happens because transformations are applied things. 
If you have one or a chain of transforms or even a transform matrix applied to your element when you change the `transform-origin` afterward that means you are applying your current transformations again from the start from a different origin. `transform` property is not cumulative.

So how to solve this?

It depends on the transformation type, but the approach is the same collecting data and getting delta values.

For example, in your case rotation.

As I believe the `transform-origin` starts from the center.
When you apply the rotation the origin point turns about the origin.

At the same time, your `top right` point turns also around the origin.

You should find the initial location of your `top-right` point before any rotation.

Then also find the point after the last rotation.

When you change the `transform-origin`, just after it, compensate the jump with the delta value of those two.

If the applied transformation was a scale, the delta would be the new width - old width

and new height - old height etc.

This answer is for just to point to the right direction.

Applying this approach is a bit complex, might involve `matrix transforms` for ease and needs some trial and error to define `+ -` signs while calculating all these.

I have a pen which I achieved this behavior but it is a long code.

You can take a look at it.

The `transform-origin` is the blue target.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLEedg?editors=0010